# Multi select with controlShouldRenderValue set to true not working in Table

Tags: reactjs, select, html-table, multi-select

I have a table who's header contains a row of selects. I am trying to display the selections under their respective selects however the selections only show under one of the selects. Im not sure whats going wrong here.

I have a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-multiselcts-fwhsus?file=/src/App.js

In my code the selections are updating underneath the first select when I change any one of the selects. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the same onChange callback.
The problem is in the parameters of this function.
`field` is not a string, it's an object.
So in the switch statement, only default case is executed.
It would be better to set onChange callback respectively.

```
onChange={e => setLocation(e.target.value)}
onChange={e => setPractice(e.target.value)}
...
```